# Should I use "years ahead" or "years after" in this case?

Tags: word-choice, time, adverbial-phrases

> You had the chance of living for one hour on this same day *10 years ahead* and fulfilling one wish to see yourself in the future.

Should I use *10 years ahead* or *10 years after* or something else in this case?

Comment: I find your sentence confusing. What exactly is happening? Is someone in the present being given the opportunity to see what would happen 10 years in the future? Or will they be given the chance to relive an hour from today 10 years from now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. I would say:

> You had the chance of living for one hour on this same day 10 years **later** and fulfilling one wish to see yourself in the future.

or

> You had the chance of living for one hour on this same day 10 years **in the future** and fulfilling one wish to see yourself in the future.

*ahead* is is not used this way. Maybe not in time phrases in general.
*after* as a preposition needs an object, as in *after school*.